# Notification Not Showing In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin and Android Studio to try and push a Notification in a test app. I followed the instructions in the Android Developers site on How to create a Notification (https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) but I seem to be doing something wrong as my Notification is not showing anywhere. Here's my code:

```
 val intent = Intent(context, Profile::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.context, 0, intent, 0);
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this.context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true)
            val mNotificationManager = message.context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            with(mNotificationManager) {
                notify(123, builder.build())
```

I really don't know what I'm missing so I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should post the link of the website you are referring to in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your code, you are not creating a **Notification channel**.

*Notification channel is necessary from **Android Oreo** and above*

So if you are running the app Android O and above devices without a notification channel, your notification won't show up.

### Create Notification Channel

```
fun createNotificationChannel() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channelId = "all_notifications" // You should create a String resource for this instead of storing in a variable
            val mChannel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "General Notifications",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            mChannel.description = "This is default channel used for all other notifications"

            val notificationManager =
                mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
        }
    }
```

Then create a notification using the same **channelId** while creating a notification.

```
createNotificationChannel()
val channelId = "all_notifications" // Use same Channel ID
val intent = Intent(context, Profile::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.context, 0, intent, 0);
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this.context, channelId) // Create notification with channel Id
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!")
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true)
val mNotificationManager =
    message.context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
with(mNotificationManager) {
    notify(123, builder.build())
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
val intent = Intent(context, Profile::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.context, 0, intent, 0)

val mNotificationManager =
    message.context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
mNotificationManager

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {//Don't forget this check

    val channel = NotificationChannel (
        channelId,
        "my_notification",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
    )

    channel.enableLights(true)
    channel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
    channel.enableVibration(false)

    
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this.context, "channel_id")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true)

    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)//Notice this
    mNotificationManager.notify(123, builder.build())
}

else {

    //Create Notifcation for below Oreo


}
```

Does your Logcat say something like:

```
E/NotificationManager: notifyAsUser: tag=null, id=123, user=UserHandle{0}
```

Also have a look at your line:

```
val intent = Intent(context, Profile::class.java)
```

IF all else fails create a test Actvity with hello world.

And then make the line look like:

```
val intent = Intent(context, testActivity::class.java)
```

Remember to add the activity to your Manifest

The following line

```
 val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.context, 0, intent, 0);
```

should not have a semi colon. Kotin doesn't need this.
Is Profile your Class or System Class?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this method and you can pass message and title dynamically :

```
private fun showNotification(title: String?, body: String?) {
    val intent = Intent(this, Profile::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

    val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer but this doesn't work either

Comment: Try to change the notificationId to a positive non zero value in this string: notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())

Comment: hope you have changed the id of notifications

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tried it and still wont work @easy_breezy

Comment: do you mean that i should make sure that i dont have two notifications with the same id @haresh?

Comment: it's the only notification i have on my code so the same id beeing used twice for notifications shouldnt be an issue @haresh